# Add HTML element using AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, tags

I am generating a `li` using AJAX depending upon the value returned by the database and am trying to apply jQuery to the dynamically generated `li`, but it is not working. Can anyone help?

My code is

```
$('.chkbox1').change(function(){
       if($(this).is(':checked'))
       {
       var grpid=this.getAttribute('id')
       //alert(grpid);
       $.ajax({

   type:"POST",
   url:"<?php print $this->Url ?>index.php/presentation/multimedia/getusers?grpid="+grpid,
   data:"grpid="+grpid,
   success:function(response){
               var data=jQuery.parseJSON(response);
               var str="";
                //alert(data[0]['first_name']);
               for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
               {
                  str=str+"<div class='img_block'><ul><li id='"+i+"'><img src='<?php print BASE_URL?>libs/publish_cart/product_img/1.jpg' class='items' height='80' alt='' /><br clear='all' /> <input type='checkbox' id='"+i+"' class='chkbox'/><div class='item_name'>"+data[i]['first_name']+"</div></li></ul> </div>";
                  $(".user").html(str);


               }


}

   });
```

The code for the `li` chkbox is below. I want it so that on a click on the check box the value is added on cart but nothing happens. If I write static `li` code, then it works.

```
var Arrays=new Array();




            $('.chkbox').change(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {

        var thisID    = $(this).attr('id');

        var itemname  = $(this).parent().find('.item_name').html();
        var itemprice = 12;

        if(include(Arrays,thisID))
        {
            var price    = $('#each-'+thisID).children(".shopp-price").find('em').html();
            var quantity = $('#each-'+thisID).children(".shopp-quantity").html();
            quantity = parseInt(quantity)+parseInt(1);

            var total = parseInt(itemprice)*parseInt(quantity);

            $('#each-'+thisID).children(".shopp-price").find('em').html(total);
            $('#each-'+thisID).children(".shopp-quantity").html(quantity);

            var prev_charges = $('.cart-total span').html();
            prev_charges = parseInt(prev_charges)-parseInt(price);

            prev_charges = parseInt(prev_charges)+parseInt(total);
            $('.cart-total span').html(prev_charges);

            $('#total-hidden-charges').val(prev_charges);
        }
        else
        {
            Arrays.push(thisID);

            var prev_charges = $('.cart-total span').html();
            prev_charges = parseInt(prev_charges)+parseInt(itemprice);

            $('.cart-total span').html(prev_charges);
            $('#total-hidden-charges').val(prev_charges);

            var Height = $('#cart_wrapper').height();
            $('#cart_wrapper').css({height:Height+parseInt(45)});

            $('#cart_wrapper .cart-info').append('<div class="shopp" id="each-'+thisID+'"><div class="label">'+itemname+'</div><div class="shopp-price"> $<em>'+'abc'+'</em></div><span class="shopp-quantity">1</span><img src="<?php print BASE_URL?>libs/publish_cart/remove.png" class="remove" /><br class="all" /></div>');

        }
                }




    });
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: What does the javascript console say? Any error?

Comment: You have to use jQuery's `live` function for listening to events of dynamically created elements.

Comment: @sharethis **NO** , live is deprecated, should not be used and was horribly wrong to begin with. It was replaced by _on_

Answer (score 2):

You shoul bind click events after appending html dynamically. Do it following way:

```
$('.chkbox').on("change", chkboxChange);

function chkboxChange() {
    //place your code from "$('.chkbox').change(function(){" here;
}
```

After ajax request in a success callback do:

```
success:function(response){
//your logic
    $('.chkbox').off("change").on("change", chkboxChange); //bind event handlers
}
```

Comment: Nice to hear that this is the modern way, I like it much more than `live`.